# What are the minimum requirements to run RestComm?

Tags: restcomm

I'm trying to run restcomm via docker on a core i5 @ 2.30GHz machine with 4GB RAM. OS is Ubuntu 14 server edition, so there is no overhead of GUI.

When the container is started the memory is fully utilized, the cpu load goes insane and the container doesn't respond in an orderly fashion.

I know the details I'm providing are very vague but I couldn't find what are the minimum requirements in any documentation and can't figure out why memory and cpu are overloaded.

Comment: In principle resources used by docker shouldn't be a great deal more than non-docker installation. The differentiating factor, and the reason it's eating up so much memory, is the 'docker-proxy' processes that take care of the port mapping. For some reason each port mapped results in a separate process in the system and if you add all those up you can easily get to around 3,2 Gb of additional memory in the case of Restcom! Seems that the docker folks are still working on that: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11185. You can try some of the workarounds found there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on what @atsakiridis mentioned. You can reduce the number of ports exposed so it consume less memory. Using the following command should consume less memory as we open only 50 ports for the media :

```
docker run  -i --name=restcomm-myInstance -v /var/log/restcomm/:/var/log/restcomm/ -e STATIC_ADDRESS="192.168.0.44" -e MEDIASERVER_LOWEST_PORT="65500" -e MEDIASERVER_HIGHEST_PORT="65535" -e ENVCONFURL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/master/scripts/restcomm_env_locally.sh" -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 9990:9990 -p 5060:5060 -p 5061:5061 -p 5062:5062 -p 5063:5063 -p 5060:5060/udp -p 65500-65535:65500-65535/udp restcomm/restcomm:latest
```

Comment: just leaving a note here for whoever comes across this that port forwarding is not necessary if you use the docker `--net=host` option, which is also the recommended option for running restcomm containers in production.

Answer (score 1):

It's been sometime since your question, but it seems the `:latest` docker image starts 2 java processes (as *agafox* pointed out in [RestComm/RestComm-Docker#109](https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/pull/109#issuecomment-311270896) ).

One of the 2 processes uses `-Xms=2048` and the other `-Xms=1048` (yes, this is not a typo... at least, not my typo... :) ), meaning the container would need at least ~3GB ram to run.

Even if your system has enough memory, please ensure docker is allowed to use this memory. (My default was 2GB).